# reading and writing app.config in C#

Tags: c#, app-config

I understand there are lot of references to `app.config` in this forum, but I am posting this question here as I think my question is very direct.

My `app.config` looks like this...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="MySection.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="MySection.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <MySection.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="DEVICE_ID_VERSION" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1.0.0.0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DEVICE_ID_ID" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0000 0001</value>
            </setting>
        </MySection.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="PInvoke" publicKeyToken="83380E73B2486719" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.19.0" newVersion="3.0.19.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Utilities" publicKeyToken="83380E73B2486719" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.18.0" newVersion="3.0.18.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <applicationSettings>
        <MySection.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="CurrentLogFile" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1</value>
            </setting>
        </MySection.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have added the new `CurrentLogFile` key from the `Settings.Settings` designer page as an `Application` key. I need to read this on application startup and write to it when there is a change in the logfile number at runtime.

The following code that I wrote is unable to re-write the `Setting` key. It creates an entirely new entry in the config file:

```cs
int curLogFile = Settings.Default.CurrentLogFile;
curLogFile = curLogFile +1;

// Update the new log file number to the config "CurrentLogFile" key
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

bool bReadOnly = config.AppSettings.Settings.IsReadOnly();
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("CurrentLogFile");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("CurrentLogFile", curLogFile.ToString());

// Save the configuration file.
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

// Force a reload of a changed section.
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
Settings.Default.Reload();
```

The new `CurrentLogFile` is created at the top of the config file just after the `</configSections>` closing tag, as shown below:

```xml
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="MySection.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
            <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="MySection.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    **<appSettings>
        <add key="CurrentLogFile" value="2" />
    </appSettings>**
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <MySection.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="DEVICE_ID_VERSION" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1.0.0.0</value>
            </setting>
        </MySection.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Utilities" publicKeyToken="83380E73B2486719" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.18.0" newVersion="3.0.18.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <applicationSettings>
        <MySection.Properties.Settings>
            **<setting name="CurrentLogFile" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1</value>
            </setting>**
        </MySection.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

This creates duplicate entries of the `CurrentLogFile` key (both highlighted with `**`, the new one at the top).

Am I using the wrong function for key writing?

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default is the same as the <applicationSettings> area of the config file. config.AppSettings.Settings is the <appSettings>. 2 different areas , so you are reading the value 1 from <applicationSettings>, and storing its value+1 (2) in <appSettings>

Answer (score 1):

Your code allows access only to the `<appSettings>` section in `<add key="CurrentLogFile" value="2" />` format.
For read/write `<userSettings>` and `<applicationSettings>` you should use standard Settings.settings file, that will do the entries in the following format `<setting name="CurrentLogFile" serializeAs="String"> <value>1</value> </setting>`
The variable name used in the project will be `string readonly YourNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.CurrentLogFile`, because you put it in application scope. User scope allows rewriting:

```
<userSettings>
    <MySection.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="DEVICE_ID_VERSION" serializeAs="String">
           <value>1.0.0.0</value>
        </setting>
    </MySection.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>

MySection.Properties.Settings.Default.DEVICE_ID_VERSION = "1.5.0.0";
MySection.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Using userSettings will store the changes some other place under %APPDATA% but you CAN write your own SettingsProvider class that might modify the original config file instead of writing the changes somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **XML** reading and writing method for this Config file 
because basic architecture of app.config and XML are same