# Changing the connection String in App.config after Installing an Application & application should accept the changes mande in config file

Tags: c#, app-config, setup-deployment

Question:

After publish and installed an windows application i would like to change the connection string present in the App.config file ( 3 Tire-Architecture). the changed connection string should be understood by already installed application. How to do it.

---

I have this App.config content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="a" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;database=billing"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

---

in Form1 ( say ) & I have gridview1, whose datasource will take from above Connection String.    Now i want to change it without re-publishing application. How to solve this task ?

---

Answer (score 1):

You need to create methods to write to app.config and also read from app.config.

Change your data access layer to accept a connection string read from your config file and you are good to go.

There are hundreds of articles on the internet on how to do this.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568549/reading-and-writing-app-config-in-c-sharp) will get you started.